# setContentView as a Class That Extends SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview

I need to set my content view as a class that extends `SurfaceView` but when I do so, I can't access the `ImageViews`, `TextViews`, etc. defined in my **main.xml** file. If I tried getting an `ImageView` for example, it'll be `null`. So how can I have the elements defined in my **main.xml** layout in my `SurfaceView` class?

Answer (score 0):

`SurfaceView` is a `View` not a `ViewGroup`. This means you cannot have children for it in traditional way. You need to draw the children yourself.

This example gives you more details on how to use `SurfaceView`: http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame2.html

Comment: That page is horrible -- it extends SurfaceView and declares an `onDraw()` method, which it explicitly calls once when the Surface is first created. It's essentially just using a custom View but adding the additional cost of a mostly-unused Surface. Don't do anything that page says.

Comment: @fadden I assume you didn't move on with the tutorial?

Comment: I deliberately said "that page" rather than "that site". I have spent a fair bit of time on stackoverflow helping fix problems arising from that specific code arrangement, so seeing it as a starting point makes me sad, because there will be people who grab that as a foundation and carry on. Until the code on that page is bracketed with a big "THIS IS THE WRONG WAY, DO NOT DO THIS", I'm going to consider it harmful.

Comment: And if those people who don't study what they read and suffer consequences of blind copy pasting, how will they ever learn ;)